# mysql dynamic pivot table group

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I am doing dynamic pivot from some tables:

```
select 
spec.id, 
'Spec1', 
(if(DATE_FORMAT(schedule.data,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2019-11-12', DATE_FORMAT(data,'%H:%i'),0)) as "12-11-2019",
(if(DATE_FORMAT(schedule.data,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2019-11-14', DATE_FORMAT(data,'%H:%i'),0)) as "14-11-2019",
(if(DATE_FORMAT(schedule.data,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2019-11-19', DATE_FORMAT(data,'%H:%i'),0)) as "19-11-2019"
from service_spec inner join spec on spec.id = service_spec.spec_id
     left join schedule on service_spec.spec_id = schedule.spec_id 
     where spec.id = 506
     group by schedule.data
     order by spec.name
```

this is query returned this

```
id  Spec1   12.11.2019  14.11.2019  19.11.2019
508 Spec1   10:00           0           0
508 Spec1   10:30           0           0
508 Spec1   11:00           0           0
508 Spec1   11:30           0           0
508 Spec1   12:00           0           0
508 Spec1   0               0           10:00
508 Spec1   0               0           10:30
508 Spec1   0               0           11:00
508 Spec1   0               0           11:30
508 Spec1   0               0           12:00
```

and this my expectations:

```
id  Spec1   12.11.2019  14.11.2019  19.11.2019
508 Spec1   10:00       0           10:00
508 Spec1   10:30       0           10:30
508 Spec1   11:00       0           11:00
508 Spec1   11:30       0           11:30
508 Spec1   12:00       0           12:00
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Please share as formatted text rather than images.

Comment: What datatype is `schedule.data`?

Comment: schedule.data - it's DATETIME

Comment: Can you create a sample data using fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7)

Comment: Of course. Link [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8e814b65d0309ddb421d45d24e2fe398)

Comment: The select query which you posted here doesn't show any result.

Comment: Just edit your post by replacing it into 506 and the db fiddle in post rather than in comments.

Comment: btw what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get a working time for a employee. Seems like calendar. I have a services, when select one - i need get a list employees, who must provide this service and them working time

Comment: so will it be static records of all like for 12th 6 records, 14th 6 records....and so on?

Comment: Here's a Stored procedure to create (and optionally run) a pivot dynamically:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  You need conditional aggregation but you don't have a column for it.

You can create one using `row_number()`:

```
select sc_id, 'Spec1', 
       max(case when date(sc_data) = '2019-11-12'
                then date_format(sc_data, '%H:%i')
           end) as "12-11-2019",
       max(case when date(sc_data) = '2019-11-14'
                then date_format(sc_data, '%H:%i')
           end) as "14-11-2019",
       max(case when date(sc_data) = '2019-11-19'
                then date_format(sc_data, '%H:%i')
           end) as "19-11-2019"
from (select s.id, sc.data as sc_data,
             row_number() over (partition by date(sc.data) order by sc_data) as seqnum
      from service_spec ss inner join
           spec s
           on s.id = ss.spec_id left join
           schedule sc
           on ss.spec_id = sc.spec_id 
      where s.id = 506 and
            date(sc.data) in ('2019-11-12', '2019-11-14', '2019-11-19')
     ) s
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

In pre-8.0 versions of MySQL, you can do something similar with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the below query,

This will work when per day entry is max of 10 and per day entry should match all the dates.

```
select
    id,
    name,
    substring_index(substring_index(col1, ',', n), ',', -1) as '12-11-2019',
    substring_index(substring_index(col2, ',', n), ',', -1) as '14-11-2019',
    substring_index(substring_index(col3, ',', n), ',', -1) as '19-11-2019',
    n
from
    (select 
        spec.id, 
        `name`, 
        group_concat(distinct if(left(schedule.data,10) = '2019-11-12', DATE_FORMAT(schedule.data,'%H:%i'),null)) as col1,
        group_concat(distinct if(left(schedule.data,10) = '2019-11-14', DATE_FORMAT(schedule.data,'%H:%i'),null)) as col2,
        group_concat(distinct if(left(schedule.data,10) = '2019-11-19', DATE_FORMAT(schedule.data,'%H:%i'),null)) as col3
    from 
        service_spec inner join spec on spec.id = service_spec.spec_id
        left join schedule on service_spec.spec_id = schedule.spec_id 
    where 
        spec.id = 506) as main
    join (SELECT @row := @row + 1 as n 
        FROM (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t 
        join (SELECT @row:=0) r ) as s_no 
        on char_length(col1) - char_length(replace(col1, ',', '')) >= n - 1;
```

**Output:**

> ```
>  id | name  | 12-11-2019 | 14-11-2019 | 19-11-2019 |  n
> --: | :---- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | -:
> 506 | Spec1 | 18:00      | 18:00      | 18:00      |  1
> 506 | Spec1 | 18:30      | 18:30      | 18:30      |  2
> 506 | Spec1 | 19:00      | 19:00      | 19:00      |  3
> 506 | Spec1 | 19:30      | 19:30      | 19:30      |  4
> 506 | Spec1 | 20:00      | 20:00      | 20:00      |  5
> 506 | Spec1 | 20:30      | 20:30      | 20:30      |  6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a45234657a8877c172a47e182915328e)*